# Tail bound on the RKHS norm of a zero-mean Gaussian process

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, measure-concentration, gaussian

Let $f \sim \mathcal{GP}(0, K)$ be a zero-mean Gaussian process defined on a compact set $\mathcal{D} \subset \mathbb{R}^d$, where $K \colon \mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is the covariance kernel. A random function sampled from such a GP can also be regarded as a member of the RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ with kernel $K$. Thus, we can consider the random variable $\|f \|_{ \mathcal{H}}$.

It would be interesting to see the tail behavior of such a random variable. That is, can we develop an inequality of the form
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P} \big ( \| f \|_{ \mathcal{H}} > q(\delta)  \big ) \leq \delta, \qquad \forall \delta \in (0,1). 
\end{align}
It would be great if we could characterize $q(\delta)$.

The motivation of this problem is from extending finite-dimensional Gaussian random vectors to infinite dimensions. For a finite-dimensional Gaussian random vector $v \sim N(0, \Sigma)$, we can easily get a tail bound for $\| v\|_2$, the Euclidean norm of $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, if the RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite dimensional, then $\mathbb P(f\in\mathcal{H})=0$ -- see e.g. [Corollary 4.10](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02582). So, no inequality of the desired form exists in infinite dimensions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your pointer. From Section 4.1.3 of this paper, Gaussian process can be represented as an infinite sequence $\sum_{i\in I} z_i \cdot \lambda_i ^{1/2} \phi_i$ where $z_i \sim N(0,1)$. Indeed the RKHS norm of $f\sim \mathcal{GP}$ is infinity.

Comment: @Steve : Yes, this is another way to come to the same conclusion.